LLM computes wrong dates
I'm encountering challenges with handling dates while using GPT-4 on Azure OpenAI. Specifically, I'm trying to extract deadlines from large email threads and convert phrases like "by next Tuesday" into actual dates based on the email's sent date.
For example, when I instruct the model to interpret "by next Tuesday" from an email sent on 5 April 2024, it should correctly identify the next Tuesday. However, the model misinterprets this, and even when it appears to understand, it calculates incorrect dates. For instance, it might output "by 12 April 2024," which is a Friday, not a Tuesday.
Has anyone else experienced similar issues or have tips on how to improve the model's accuracy in date calculations? Any guidance or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you!
I did try to ask the model to explain how it computes the date. It told me ''Leadership decisions are needed by next Tuesday from 5 April 2024, which implies a decision by 12 April 2024'' (April 12 is a Friday)
I tried giving examples and explaining the rationale. It didn't work either:
"Guidelines for deadline date calculations:

Ensure that all deadlines are specified with full dates or clearly referenced to full dates.
Example of an email thread composed of 2 emails:
Email 1 - date: 4 january 2024 - "Hi May, we received the validation from Finance for the budget, still waiting for Legal. John"
Email 2 - date: 2 january 2024 - "Hi May, we have a challenge on project ABC. Marketing budget haven't been approved yet. I chased Finance and Legal and asked them to get back to us by next Monday the latest. John"

Incorrect output: 'Finance and Legal should validate marketing budget by next Monday'
-> Correct output 1: 'Finance and Legal should validate marketing budget by next Monday from 2 January 2024'
-> Correct output 2: 'Finance and Legal should validate marketing budget by Monday 8 January 2024'
Rationale: validation should be done by next Monday from the date of the email mentioning this deadline, which is dated 2 January 2024. Therefore, the decision should be made by 8 January 2024."

Based on my experience, LLMs do not have the concept of current date. Please modify the prompt and include the current date and the day of the week. For example, you can include the following text in your prompt: For context, today's date is 18th of April, 2024 and the day is Thursday.

An LLM does not calculate anything. GPT-4 is just a likely text generator optimized for instruction following. While it's an impressive piece of tech, it won't get the answer right 100% of the time when it comes to maths.
You might be able to get better results by improving your prompt, using examples in a Chain of Thought or Few Shot pattern. However, this can still lead to errors because of the nature of an LLM. They are not calculators.
You could have the LLM extract the dates and then use code to compute the right answers.
